# Passing GET parameters in JediTable loadurl

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Background:
I am creating a php generated shifts scheduler for my hospital's Operating Rooms. On X Axis I'm plotting days, on Y the ORs. I'm using Jeditable to edit in place each cell generating a dropdown from a select that load data.

Php Code:

```
$query = $db->query('select sp.id, sp.sigla from lista_specializzandi sp where sp.id not in (select sp.id from lista_specializzandi sp, esigenze e where sp.id = e.specializzando and e.giorno='.$giorno.' and (e.tipologia=2 or e.tipologia=3 or e.tipologia=4 or e.tipologia =5 or e.tipologia=6 or e.tipologia=7))');
$esiSelect = array();
while ($disp = $db->fetch_array($query)) {
    $esiSelect[$disp['id']] = $disp['sigla'];
}
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".turnistica").editable('save_turnistica.php', {
      data        : <?php echo json_encode($esiSelect); ?>,
      type        : 'select',
      indicator   : 'Salvo...',
      tooltip   :   'Clicca per modificare',
      placeholder   :   '&nbsp;',
      onblur    :   'submit',
      event     :   'click',
      submitdata : function(value, settings) {
        return {"giorno" : $(this).attr('id_giorno'), "sala" : $(this).parent().attr('id_riga')};
      }
    });
  });  
    </script>
```

The table:

```
<section class="fluid" id="flip-scroll">
            <table id="foglioEsigenze" class="table-bordered table-striped table-condensed cf full">
            <col class="col10">
            <?php 
foreach ($cals as $c)
        echo
        '<col class="dw'.$c->isFeriale.$c->isFestivo.'"></col>';
?>
              <thead class="cf verde_trasp bold text-white">
                  <tr>
            <th class="col1">&nbsp;</th>
            <?php 
foreach ($cals as $c)
        echo
        '<th class="dw'.$c->isFeriale.$c->isFestivo.'"><span style="font-size:9px">'.substr($c->giornoNome, 0, 3).'</span> '.$c->d.'</th>';
?>
          </tr>
              </thead>
                <tbody>

          <?php
while ($s = $db->fetch_array($indice)) {
        echo
        '<tr class="Row" data-blocco="'.$s['blocco'].'" id_riga="'.$s['id'].'"><td style="text-align: left;">'.$s['sigla'].'</td>';
        foreach ($cals as $g) {
        echo
        '<td class="turnistica" style="text-align: center;" id_giorno="'.$g->id.'">';
        global $db;
        $sql = 'select sp.sigla from turnistica t, lista_specializzandi sp where t.giorno = '.$g->id.' and t.riga='.$s['id'].' and t.specializzando = sp.id limit 1';
        $query = $db->query($sql);
        $sigla = $db->fetch_array($query);
        echo $sigla['sigla'];
        '</td>';
        '</tr>';            
        }
}
?>
                </tbody>
      </table>
    </section>
```

... So far so good!
Now I need to create a dropdown that auto remove physicians after I insert them in a column.
I thought this solution but I don't know why it's not working.

1) I moved all the load code to an external php file:

```
<?php  

require ('includes/initialise.php');  
global $db;
$giorno     = $_GET['giorno'];


$query = $db->query('select sp.id, sp.sigla from lista_specializzandi sp where sp.id not in (select sp.id from lista_specializzandi sp, esigenze e where sp.id = e.specializzando and e.giorno='.$giorno.' and (e.tipologia=2 or e.tipologia=3 or e.tipologia=4 or e.tipologia =5 or e.tipologia=6 or e.tipologia=7))');
$esiSelect = array();
while ($disp = $db->fetch_array($query)) {
    $esiSelect[$disp['id']] = $disp['sigla'];
}
echo json_encode($esiSelect);

?>
```

2) I called it by loadurl in the javascript adding the attribute of the element

```
loadurl        : "disponibili.php?giorno=" + $(this).attr("id_giorno"),
```

All the problems are coming from the Javascript variable I am passing. But I googled a lot without solving the problem.

How can I fix this?

@dcaswell: I am not able to pass the javascript variable in 2) to the loadurl file, so no action can be performed before populating the json list. I am definitely missing something. Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: You don't actually explain what the problem is. Could you please edit your question and add the error message or describe what is failing?

Comment: Is it Jedi Table, JEditable, Jeditable...?  (Pretty sure the last, but don't want to assume  ;)

Comment: @lzkata: it's Jeditable plugin.